# Number of couples $(a, b)$ where $a$ and $b$ are elements of the same powerset and are pairwise disjoint

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ be a finite set with 4 elements. How many possible distinct couples $(a,b)$ exist such that $a\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $b\in \mathcal{P}(A)$ where $ \mathcal{P}(A)$ is the powerset of $A$, such that $a$ and $b$ have an empty intersection?

Attempted solution:

Given a couple, we consider the combinations  $C(4,1), C(4,2), C(4,3), C(4,4)$ as the first place of the couple.

then for the couple having all the possible $C(4,1)$ of the elements, we compute in how many ways the second place of the couple can be filled. We should have:

1. $C(4,1) C(3,1) $ + $C(4,1) C(3,2) $ + $C(4,1) C(3,3) $

   since we can associate for each singleton of $A$ another singleton of $A$ distinct from the first chosen, or we can associate a 2-elements set not having any element in common with the singleton, or we can associate a 3-element set not having elements in common with the first singleton chosen.

We proceed with this reasoning with the following computation:

2. $C(4,2) C(2,1) $ + $C(4,2) C(2,2) $
3. $C(4,3) C(1,1) $

the sum of the terms in 1, 2, 3 should give us all the possible couples where the two element of the powerset have a null intersection. Is the reasoning correct?

Can it be generalized with sets of $n$ cardinality in the following way?

First compute $C(n,1) C(n-1,1) + C(n,1) C(n-1,2) + \dots + C(n,1) C(n-1,n-1) $

Second compute, $C(n,2) C(n-2,1) + C(n,2) C(n-2,2) + \dots + C(n,1) C(n-2,n-2) $

...

At the end, compute $C(n,n-1) C(1,1) $

Comment: Yes that expression looks correct assuming you require non-empty sets. However it is easier to note that each element can be in $A$ or $B$ or neither. So there are $3^n$ possible pairs. Of these there are $3^n - 2^n -2^n + 1$ pairs in which neither set is empty.

Comment: @Asinomás thanks for the answer. I do not think i have understood why the expression $ 3^{n}n− 2^{n}n− 2^{n}n+1 $ should lead to the same result. In particular, why do we have 3 to the n possible pairs?

Comment: I mixed up the notation, but for every element of $A$ there are $3$ options for it, put it only in $a$, put it only in $b$ or put it in neither, and then you have to substract the cases when one of $a$ or $b$ is empty.